# Black flying bug infestation

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image: Flying black bug]

What is this black bug in my house. There is literally an infestation. They are everywhere. The size of a small tick. They fly and just keep coming. Im from pakistan, lahore.

I've never seen these before in my life and have lived in this house for over 10 years.

Comment: Have you noticed anything about their behavior? Are they attracted to anything in particular? Light, water, food, windows, each other?  Do they stay airborne a lot, for long periods of time, or just "buzz" a short distance before landing and walking around again?